# app_offline.htm and "directory listing denied"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, deployment

When I use the "publish web site" feature in visual studio 2008, it automatically places a app_offline.htm on the web server while it is pushing the files up. If you navigate to http://MyWebSite.com/somepage.aspx  you will see the application offline page, which is good.

However if you navigate to http://MyWebSite.com you will get a directory listing denied error message. 
Is there any way to correct this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not placing any web.config there to allow viewing pages it will give that error. You can set a default page in IIS though.

Answer (score 2):

What is the default document? If the default document is a .htm(l) file, which won't pass through the .NET ISAPI (If you are using IIS 6 or less or on 7+ in classic mode), then .NET won't have the chance to intercept the request and display the offline page.